# token introspection endpoint in ADFS 4.0

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, oauth, adfs, adfs4.0

Is there any token introspection endpoint available in ADFS?

I am using the oauth2 configuration to get the token.  I can verify the token in the resource server by jwks keys. I am able to check the validity of the token. but not the actual status. I was trying using the [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-resource-server#opaque-server) for checking the status. but I can't find the introspection endpoint.

[This](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7662) OAuth standard specifies that there will be one introspection endpoint.

I am not sure that https://adfs_domain/adfs/oauth2/token/introspect this URL is correct. but when I tried I got

> Error details: MSIS7065: There are no registered protocol handlers on
> path /adfs/oauth2/token/introspect to process the incoming request.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - this endpoint is not implemented.

You can see the list of available endpoints in the ADFS wizard / Services / Endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can try to add an additional endpoint and check. Maybe ADFS does not supports.
Example:

```
Set-AdfsEndpoint -TargetAddressPath "/adfs/oauth2/token/introspect" -Proxy $True
```